# Osmdroid - simulating fake GPS locations

Tags: android, osmdroid

How can I fake a (new) current location for the map?

Reason for NOT using the MOCKUP_SERVICE anymore is (1) errors in Android Studio Lollipot environment and (2) making it more flexibel.

Comment: `Question 1: What I see is that the 'receivedCenter' is just near N0 0.000 E0 0.000. How come?` because the location that you are using to set center is 0. `Question 2: how can I fake a (new) current location for the map?` Simply create a location object to some location and pass it to map or may be you can add a layer representing current location.

Comment: Q1: Humor ;_)
Setting the center = 52.12022483023131,6.600634222465725
Reading the center to:   0,6600633,0
Q2: how can I pass it directly to the map?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar - yes, you were right. I put the 'altitude' in the latitude. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Write the following fake LocationProvider.
You can use your own GPS class for giving for example the last location.

```
class MyMockupGpsMyLocationProvider implements IMyLocationProvider {
    IMyLocationConsumer listener = null;
    Location newLoc = GPS.getLastKnownLocation(); // or other class
    public boolean startLocationProvider(IMyLocationConsumer var1) {
        listener = var1;
        return true;
    }
    public void stopLocationProvider() { }
    public Location getLastKnownLocation() {
        return GPS.getLastKnownLocation(); // or other class
    }
    public void updateLocation( Location newLoc) {
        listener.onLocationChanged( newLoc, (IMyLocationProvider) this);
    }
}
```

Step 2: Attach it to your MyOverlay

```
MyMockupGpsMyLocationProvider fakeGpsLocations = new MyMockupGpsMyLocationProvider();
myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation(fakeGpsLocations );
```

Step 3: provide fake GPS locations. Here by calling the updateLocation().

```
mockupGpsPrivder.updateLocation(currentLocation);
```

Comment: Good practice is to accept your own answer if you found out yourself. That stops others from looking for solutions.

Comment: OK. You can accept an 'own' answer only after two days ;-)